# Using groovy to open a web page, when the code runs on a different computer

Tags: groovy

I have an interesting one that I am not sure how to address.  I have access to a website that provides a front end into a database.  As part of that front end I am able to write groovy code that executes on their server.  I am looking to add some capabilities that their front end does not already have.  To do so I need to direct users to another web site from within the groovy code.  **How can I create either a pop up or re-direct to another web page from within groovy?**  I know how to do it in javascript, but cannot run javascript on their page.  I have spent hours looking through these pages I have not found anything to help.

One additional point.  I cannot just direct my users to the new page due to the passing of security information I need to inherit from the original front end.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some more details, for example what the interaction with the remove website looks like.

Comment: In what specific environment is the code executing?  Is it within Grails or is the code being treated as a Groovlet (Groovy servlet)?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could try interacting with the remove website using the [HTTP Builder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/)

Other than that you could always do a simple HTTP redirect but I'm not sure that would fulfil your requirements. To redirect from a controller do:

```
redirect(url:"http://grails.org")
```